# Choose couple of values from a list without replacements

Tags: python, numpy

I search the fastest way to draw many couple of two values from a list so those two values are always different in the couple. The naive method I coded is very slow, so I'm pretty sure that they are more efficient way to do that.

```
import numpy
listx = range(10)
number_of_couples=10000
data=numpy.empty([number_of_couples,2])

for i in xrange(number_of_couples):
   data[i] =numpy.random.choice(listx,size=2,replace=False)
```

Comment: Do you want all two length combinations that are different?

Comment: Is `listx` really that small in practice? Because that has a major impact on what is an "efficient" answer.

Comment: I added data[i]=numpy.choice... is it clearer? I need that data[i,0]!=data[i,1] and the drawn couple data[i] in a list without replacement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion is to use [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) to cache all combinations in a list before drawing pairs from it with `random.choice`:

```
import itertools
import random
import numpy

listx = range(10)
number_of_couples = 10000
permutations = list(itertools.permutations(listx, 2))
data = numpy.array([random.choice(permutations) for _ in range(number_of_couples)])
```

By testing your solution with IPython, it takes an average of 489 ms:

```
489 ms ± 13.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

My suggestion is more than 25x faster:

```
17.2 ms ± 225 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Note that for `permutations`, `(x, y)` is different than `(y, x)`:

```
>>> print(list(itertools.permutations(range(3), 2)))
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
```

If in your case `(x, y)` and `(y, x)` are the same information, then use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
>>> print(list(itertools.combinations(range(3), 2)))
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2)]
```

Just one more thing: the major problem with your solution is the `data[i] =` operation, which is quite costly. Instead of creating an empty array and modifying it with the selected couples, simply creating a new array from a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) can greatly speed up the solution:

```
import numpy
listx = range(10)
number_of_couples=10000
data = numpy.array([numpy.random.choice(listx,size=2,replace=False) for i in range(number_of_couples)]) # Create a new array from the choices
```

Look how faster it is:

```
24.3 ns ± 0.554 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be fast enough for most applications, see timings below:

```
# make an example
>>> import string
>>> listx = list(string.ascii_letters)
>>> 
>>> 
>>> L = len(listx)
>>> number_of_couples = 10_000_000
>>> 
>>> idx = np.array((np.random.randint(0, L, (number_of_couples,)), np.random.randint(0, L-1, (number_of_couples,))))
>>> idx[1, idx[0] == idx[1]] = L-1
>>> 
>>> result = np.array(listx)[idx.T]
>>> 
>>> result
array([['p', 't'],
       ['O', 'F'],
       ['M', 'S'],
       ...,
       ['Q', 'k'],
       ['N', 'm'],
       ['f', 'x']], dtype='<U1')
>>> 
# sanity checks
# distribution looks flat
>>> np.bincount(idx.ravel())
array([384357, 385561, 384175, 384998, 385799, 384446, 384356, 384684,
       384305, 384072, 384993, 384346, 385302, 384518, 384659, 384142,
       383554, 384790, 384424, 384032, 383950, 385103, 384092, 384653,
       383428, 385388, 384074, 384197, 384644, 384741, 384343, 384282,
       384192, 385791, 384106, 383872, 384506, 385161, 384401, 384661,
       383978, 385547, 385571, 385941, 385416, 385325, 383997, 385201,
       383998, 384199, 385105, 384624])
# pairs are distinct
>>> np.any(idx[0] == idx[1])
False
```

Timings compared with `itertools` solution:

```
>>> def f_np(listx, number_of_couples):
...     L = len(listx)
...     idx = np.array((np.random.randint(0, L, (number_of_couples,)), np.random.randint(0, L-1, (number_of_couples,))))
...     idx[1, idx[0] == idx[1]] = L-1
...     return np.array(listx)[idx.T]
... 
>>> def f_it(listx, number_of_couples):
...     permutations = list(itertools.permutations(listx, 2))
...     return numpy.array([random.choice(permutations) for _ in range(number_of_couples)])
... 
>>> from time import perf_counter
>>> t = perf_counter(); f_it(listx, number_of_couples); s = perf_counter()
array([['s', 'm'],
       ['G', 'w'],
       ['w', 'S'],
       ...,
       ['V', 'R'],
       ['P', 'Q'],
       ['Q', 'J']], dtype='<U1')
>>> s-t
10.544860829017125
>>> t = perf_counter(); f_np(listx, number_of_couples); s = perf_counter()
array([['C', 'T'],
       ['X', 'y'],
       ['U', 's'],
       ...,
       ['U', 'M'],
       ['t', 'i'],
       ['m', 'c']], dtype='<U1')
>>> s-t
0.3759624689701013
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use method [combinations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) from itertools.

The difference with Matheus Portela's answer is that combinations are emitted in lexicographic sort order, so ['A','B'] will yield ['AB'], wherease perumation would yield ['AB', 'BA']

Comment: I need that AB and BA can be drawn. TY anyway for this precision.

Comment: In this case, see Matheus' answer, which details both solutions with performance information